# How to make the annoying 1px border that appears between the table border and table background and lets the page background show through disappear?

Tags: html, css

A 1px "border" appears inside the border that is basically the page background showing even though there is a set background color for the table. It appears basically right next to the border.

I have tried increasing the width of the border hoping it would cover it.

Here is what it looks like on my end: [what it looks like on my end][1]

Here is my css file and after it the function I want to use it in:

```
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}       
#title{
    height: 250px;
    width: 996px;
    border: 2px solid #0000ff;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #55ff55;
    text-align: center;
}
#lefty{
    height: 600px;
    width: 246px;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ff5555;
    padding: 10px;
}
#righty{
    height: 600px;
    width: 706px;
    border: 2px solid #00ff00;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: -624px;
    background-color: #5555ff;
    padding: 10px;
}
.menu{
    display: block;
    height : 20px;
    width: 236px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: #bb0000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

table, td, th{
    border: 3px solid black;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
}

function MenutIr($x)
    {
        echo '<table align="center">';
        foreach($x as $index => $ertek)  
        {       
        echo '<tr><td>'; 
        echo '<a href=?menu='.$index.' class ="menu">'.$ertek.'</a>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }

EDIT: I couldn't make the snippet work but here is a working version of it:
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<html lang = "hu">
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <style>body{
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}       
#title{
    height: 250px;
    width: 996px;
    border: 2px solid #0000ff;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #55ff55;
    text-align: center;
}
#lefty{
    height: 600px;
    width: 246px;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ff5555;
    padding: 10px;
}
#righty{
    height: 600px;
    width: 706px;
    border: 2px solid #00ff00;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: -624px;
    background-color: #5555ff;
    padding: 10px;
}
.menu{
    display: block;
    height : 20px;
    width: 236px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: #bb0000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

table, td, th{
    border: 3px solid black;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $menu[1] = "Beolvas";
        $menu[2] = "Tényező";
        $menu[3] = "Oszt";
        ?>
<?php
    function Debug($x)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($x);
        echo '</pre>';      
    }
    function MenutIr($x)
    {
        echo '<table align="center">';

        /*
        vegigmegy a tombon a 
        beirt indexek sorrendje szerint
        index - index
        ertek - a tombben hasznalt ertek        
        */
        foreach($x as $index => $ertek)  
        {       
        /*
        table row, table data - minden elemet kulon sorban jelenit meg
        */
        echo '<tr><td>'; 
        echo '<a href=?menu='.$index.' class ="menu">'.$ertek.'</a>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }

    function Olvas(&$a)
    {
        if(!isset($_POST["a"]) || $_POST["a"]==""|| !is_numeric($_POST["a"]))
        {
            /*Urlap*/
            echo '<form name="Olvas" action="" method="post">';
            echo 'a = ';        
            echo '<input name="a" type="number" min ="1" size="3"<br><br>';
            echo '<input name="gomb" type="submit" value="Mehet">';
            echo '</form>';
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {

            $a = $_POST["a"];
            $_SESSION["a"] = $a;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    function Oszt($a)
    {
        $d=1;
        for($d=1; $d <= $a; $d++)
        {
            if($a%$d==0)
            {
                echo "$d ";
            }
        }
    }

    function Tenyezo($a)
    {
        $d=2;
        echo '<table>';
        while($a>1)
        {
            if($a%$d==0)
            {   
                echo '<tr><td style= "text-align:right; border-left-style:hidden; border-top-style:hidden; border-bottom-style:hidden;">'.$a.'</td><td style= "text-align:left; border-right-style:hidden; border-top-style:hidden; border-bottom-style:hidden;">'.$d.'</td></tr>';        
                $a = $a/$d;
            }
            else
            {
                $d++;
            }
        }
        echo '<tr><td style= "text-align:right; border-left-style:hidden; border-top-style:hidden; border-bottom-style:hidden;">1</td><td style= "text-align:left; border-right-style:hidden; border-top-style:hidden; border-bottom-style:hidden;"></td></tr>';        
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>
        <div id = "title"> Php kezdetek </div>
        <div id = "lefty"> 
            <?php
                MenutIr($menu);
            ?>  
        </div>
        <div id = "righty">
            <?php

            /*ha nem volt kattintas a menure*/
            $a = 0;
            $b = 0;
            if(!isset($_GET["menu"]))
            {           
                Debug($menu);
            }
            else
            {
                switch($_GET["menu"])
                {
                    case 1: //kattintas az elso mezon
                        echo $menu[1].'<br>';
                        if(Olvas($a))
                        {
                            echo "a=$a<br>";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2: //kattintas a masodik mezon
                        echo $menu[2].'<br>';
                        if(!isset($_SESSION["a"]))
                        {
                            echo "Nincs mit osszeadni<br>";                     
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $a=$_SESSION["a"];                      
                            Tenyezo($a);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3: //kattintas a harmadik mezon
                        echo $menu[3].'<br>';
                        if(!isset($_SESSION["a"]))
                        {
                            echo "Nincs mit osszeadni<br>";                     
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $a=$_SESSION["a"];                      
                            Oszt($a);
                        }
                        break;  
                    case 4: //kattintas a harmadik mezon
                        echo $menu[4].'<br>';
                        break;
                }
            }
            ?>              
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ki0v.png
```

Comment: You can send page url. so i can check it clearly.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? The code you have here doesn't cause the problem you describe.

Comment: I don't actually know how to do that as I don't have access to a server and it is on local... I could zip up the files and send them over if that'd help...

Comment: @Floppy Edit the question and make a snippet by clicking on the `<>` icon.

Comment: @MrLister how can I send the file to you? edit: sorry, i understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "cellpadding='0' " along-with  "border-collapse: collapse;" in your table tag like this:

```
echo "<table align='center' cellpadding='0'>";
```